# How to create a calculator that calculates Current Value, Desired Value, and how much it would be to go from current to desired?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Leveling Chart]

Helloooo back here with another question as I'm making another calculator for my Role Play Group.

I'm wondering how I can make a calculator that can calculate the Experience Points required! Unfortunately 86-100 on the scale is completely different...as 100 is the max level achievable. If it's too difficult to account for the last levels, I don't mind making it 86-106.

I really don't know anything about math and formulas...so any and all help would be super appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Try `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination like-

```
=INDEX(C4:C9,MATCH(F4,INDEX(SPLIT(B4:B9,"-"),,1),1))
```

[image]

Comment: And how would I write the XP required box? in your case, F5 ?

Comment: Actually `G4` cell formula will be on `F5` cell.